# Pass a variable in bean-shell assertion Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, assertion, beanshell

I try to pass 2 variables to the BeanShell script of Jmeter but it fails with the error. However, if I pass a hardcoded string value, it works.

Beanshell assertion to compare variable AdID1 and MAdID1

```
String addrress1="${AdID1}"; 
String memberAddress1="${MAdID1}"; 

Failure1 = !addrress1.equals(memberAddress1);

if (Failure1) {
  FailureMessage = "Variables are not equal. Expected \"" + addrress1 + "\" , actual:\"" + memberAddress1 + "\"";
}


if(addrress1.equals(memberAddress1)) {
    log.info("Matched");
```

> Error:BeanShellAssertion: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException:
>   Error invoking bsh method

Answer (score 0):

Don't inline [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into scripts.

Try to use the JMeter variables in your scripts like this:

```
String addrress1= vars.get("AdID1");
String memberAddress1= vars.get("MAdID1");
```

It is advised to use [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy Language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) rather using BeanShell.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to avoid scripting and use built-in [JMeter Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html) or [Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) or [Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) and avoid scripting where possible so I would suggest going for [Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved).

The relevant configuration would be:

[image]

With regards to your script - it appears it's missing closing `}`.